# Facing problem in loading component over another component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular-routing, angular-components

I am working on Angular Project , where I am trying to load Component  over another 
without background component changes , and url of background component changes

for example -:

Suppose User working on Login component and filling login form

-> User  clicks forget password button
-> then another component forget password which loads over Login form 
**without Url and login page in the background changes**

How we can do it in Angular

I have tried with

**login.html**

```
 <div class="forget" no-lines><a (click)="forgetPassword()">Forget Password</a></div>
```

**login.ts**

```
forgetPassword() {

    let forgetpassword = this.modal.create('ForgotPassword');
    forgetpassword.present();
  }
```

where ForgotPassword is another component  but it dosen't load over login page

Comment: are you using angular material?

Comment: @MohitSaxena yes

Comment: Okay. read and follow simple steps on link  
  https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: @MohitSaxena thanks Mohit , it worked for me  , but what are the other way to do so ..